# C# - Does OR act like an Else If?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will all methods in a logical expressions be executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781832/will-all-methods-in-a-logical-expressions-be-executed)

Let me explain: let's say we have theese two codes:

```
foreach(Object o in Objs)
    if(o is Class1 || o is Class2)
        DoSomething();
```

__

```
foreach(Object o in Objs)
    if(o is Class1)
        DoSomething();
    else if(o is Class2)
        DoSomething();
```

Now, of course an OR is better in this case, but my question is different and just out of curiosity: when in the first case o is of type Class1, does the compiler stop and run the code or it checks what comes next anyway?
It would do that in the second case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`||` is short-circuiting, which means: if the first argument returns `true`, the second argument is **not evaluated**. In this way, *yes* it is broadly equivalent to your second example, but more terse.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the quick and concise reply!

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN Documentation for the || operator in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool operands. If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to true or false.

Note: That is also the case for all C-like languages (C, C++, Java, C#) that I know of.

Comment: Damn, didn't think to check on MSDN. Sorry for the useless question, but thanks for all the answers in less than a minute.

Answer (score 1):

In the operation `x || y`, `y` is evaluated only if `x` is false.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The double pipe or "||" will look from the left to the right if some condition is true, whether it will stop looking for other condition and execute the piece of code. The simple pipe or "|" will do the same thing but will check all the conditions (so generally you will prefer using "||").